# Regular Expression to avoid only special charaters

Tags: regex

i want a regular exp to allow below validations

abc        -- Valid
abc123     -- Valid
abc@def    -- Valid
abc@123    -- Valid

## $@        -- Invalid

abc&%&&    -- Invalid

My regular exp can accept special chars but it should not allow only special chars.

Answer (score 0):

By your terms "abc&%&&" should be valid, because it has non-special characters.
However, I think that the expression you are looking for is "[\w|\d]" , because it ensures that there's at lease one character that is not special.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I have given like this , but when i enter name in my text box as   abcd@ , it is not accepting.

<RegularExpression ValidationExpression="/[\w|\d]/" ErrorText="Enter valid Organization Name" />

Do I need do any changes..? Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it in the wrong format (js-like), I've edited my answer to the right pattern.